# Calculating Standard Deviation For Linear Combination Problem

Tags: probability, statistics

So here's the problem:

An airline charges the following baggage fees: 25 for the first bag and $35 for the second. Suppose 43% of passengers have no checked luggage, 38% have one piece of checked luggage and 19% have two pieces. We suppose a negligible portion of passengers check more than two bags.

Calculate the corresponding standard deviation. Give your answer to two decimal places.

I squared the following expression $(25^2 + .1444) + (60^2 \times .0361)$ and then the result I got was $27.48$ which is wrong. What am I doing wrong? I've been stuck on this problem for two hours now and It's driving me insane!

Comment: Let $X$ be the number of bags checked by a random customer. Make a table of its PMF (or PDF) $f(x)$, Find $E(X) = \sum_{x=0}^2 xf(x).$ Then look up your text's method of finding $V(X)$ from the table. The square root of that is the 'corresponding' standard deviation you seek. I have no idea how you got the expression you show, or why you squared it. An explanation of that would have been appropriate.